# "Ambiguous conversion sequence" - what is the purpose of this concept?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution, conversion-operator

In N4659 **16.3.3.1 Implicit conversion sequences** says

> **10** If several different sequences of conversions exist that each convert the argument to the parameter type, the implicit conversion sequence associated with the parameter is defined to be the unique conversion sequence designated the *ambiguous conversion sequence*. For the purpose of ranking implicit conversion sequences as described in 16.3.3.2, the ambiguous conversion sequence is treated as a user-defined conversion sequence that is indistinguishable from any other user-defined conversion sequence [Note: This rule prevents a function from becoming non-viable because of an ambiguous conversion sequence for one of its parameters.] If a function that uses the ambiguous conversion sequence is selected as the best viable function, the call will be ill-formed because the conversion of one of the arguments in the call is ambiguous.

(The corresponding section of the current draft is [12.3.3.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#10))

What is the intended purpose of this rule and the concept of *ambiguous conversion sequence* it introduces?

The note supplied in the text states that the purpose of this rule is "to prevent a function from *becoming non-viable* because of an ambiguous conversion sequence for one of its parameters". Um... What does this actually refer to? The concept of a *viable function* is defined in the [preceding](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.viable) sections of the document. It does not depend on ambiguity of conversions at all (conversions for each argument must exist, but they don't have to be unambiguous). And there seems to be no provision for a *viable* function to somehow "become non-viable" later (neither because of some ambiguity nor anything else). Viable functions are enumerated, they compete against each other for being "the best" in accordance with [certain rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best) and if there's a single "winner", the resolution is successful. At no point in this process a viable function may (or needs) to turn into a non-viable one.

The example provided within the aforementioned paragraph is not very enlightening (i.e. it is not clear what role the above rule plays in that example).

---

The question originally popped up in connection with this simple example

```
struct S
{
  operator int() const { return 0; };
  operator long() const { return 0; };
};

void foo(int) {}

int main()
{
  S s;
  foo(s);
}
```

Let's just mechanically apply the above rule here. `foo` is a viable function. There are two implicit conversion sequences from argument type `S` to parameter type `int`: `S -> int` and `S -> long -> int`. This means that per the above rule we have to "pack" them into a single *ambiguous conversion sequence*. Then we conclude that `foo` is the *best viable function*. Then we discover that it uses our *ambiguous conversion sequence*. Consequently, per the above rule the code is ill-formed.

This seems to make no sense. The natural expectation here is that `S -> int` conversion should be chosen, since it is ranked higher than `S -> long -> int` conversion. All compilers I know follow that "natural" overload resolution.

So, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think a better example would be that `foo` took a `double` argument, as then both conversion chains would be equivalent (`S` -> `int` -> `double`, versus `S` -> `long` -> `double`). That would truly be ambiguous.

Comment: Wild speculation that ambiguous conversion sequence is intended to exclude the identity conversion sequence. [Like this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hULnljNyU5ztE4d5)

Comment: @Some programmer dude: Not sure what you mean by "better". The purpose of this last example is to illustrate the contradiction: the code it is actually *valid* (at least I believe it should be). But the rule in question seems to say that it is *invalid*.

Comment: "Let's just blindly apply the above rule here. " I think that you are not supposed to, if I recall correctly. Here, there is only a single conversion sequence, because `operator int` wins against `operator long`.

Comment: @AndyG I thought the identity conversion sequence was converting `T` to `T` only.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: The quoted text doesn't say that only equal-ranked conversion sequences have to be "packed" into an *ambiguous conversion sequence*. It simply says that "If several different sequences of conversions exist..." If you have several different sequences, they have to be packed into a an *ambiguous conversion sequence*, regardless of whether one of them is better than the others or not.

Comment: @AnT I don't understand. It says " If several different sequences of conversions exist that each convert the argument to the parameter type". And here you have a user-defined conversion sequence, and are supposed to find the conversion function or constructor that is used in it. And you can unambiguously find it. So there are no "different sequences of conversions". There is only one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux a user defined conversion sequence may consist of a user defined conversion followed by a standard conversion sequence. The standard conversion sequence can convert `T` to `T` (adjusting for minor things like references)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: I don't understand what you are saying. Again: I see two different conversion sequences here `S -> int` and `S -> long -> int`. How is there only one? Note that this "packing" of multiple conversion sequences into one *ambiguous conversion sequence* is done quite early: before we begin ranking implicit conversion sequences and choosing the best viable function.

Comment: @AnT the corresponding rule to establish the `-> int` and `-> long` parts says "Overload resolution is used to select the conversion function to be invoked." (Note that this is a *nested* overload resolution with its own implicit conversion sequence, which is not to be confused with the one for `foo`). In this case, overload resolution selected `operator int` using a tie breaker ( http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match#best-2.2 ), because `int -> int` is better than `long -> int`. So there is no user defined conversion sequence here that uses `operator long`.

Comment: [I knew it is confusing](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/2288)

Comment: @cpplearner I left a comment there.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Mayb it is better to open a new issue?

Answer (score 3):

To be viable, there must be an [`implicit conversion sequence`](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics#def:conversion_sequence,implicit).

The standard could have permitted **multiple** implicit conversion sequences, but that might make the wording for determining which overload to select more complex.

So the standard ends up defining **one and exactly one** implicit conversion sequence for each argument to each parameter.  In the case where there is ambiguity, the one it uses is the *ambiguous conversion sequence*.

Once this is done, it no longer has to deal with the possibility of multiple conversion sequences of one argument to one parameter.

Imagine if we where writing this in C++.  We might have a few types:

```
namespace conversion_sequences {
  struct standard;
  struct user_defined;
  struct ellipsis;
}
```

where each has plenty of stuff in them (skipped here).

As each conversion sequence is one of the above, we define:

```
  using any_kind = std::variant< standard, user_defined, ellipsis >;
```

Now, we run into the case of there being more than one conversion sequence for a given argument and parameter.  We have two choices at this point.

We could pass around a `using any_kinds = std::vector<any_kind>` for a given argument,parameter pair, and ensure all of the logic that handles picking a conversion sequence deals with this vector...

Or we could note that the handling of a 1 or more entry vector never looks at the elements in the vector, and it is treated exactly like a kind of `user_defined` conversion sequence, until the very end at which point we generate an error.

Storing that extra state, and having the extra logic, is a pain.  We know we don't need that state, and we don't need code to handle the vector.  So we just define a sub-type of `conversion_sequence::user_defined`, and the code after it finds the preferred overload it checks if the resulting overload chosen should generate errors.

While the C++ standard is not (always) implemented in C++ and the wording doesn't have to have a 1:1 relationship with its implementation, writing a robust standard document is a kind of coding, and some of the same concerns apply.

Comment: This makes more sense when reading an older draft, where the previous paragraph said "If no sequence of conversions can be found to convert an argument to a parameter type or the conversion is otherwise ill-formed, an implicit conversion sequence cannot be formed". With the "otherwise ill-formed", I think they had the ambiguity in mind that arises when trying to find the user-defined conversion within a UCS. In current drafts the "otherwise ill-formed" part is gone.